# Determine which widget triggers the callback function in command

Tags: python, tkinter

I am coding a GUI in python using tkinter. I assgined the same callback function to the "command" argument in 3 buttons. The purpose of these buttons is to specify a directory depending on the widget name. Is there any way that I can tell which widget triggered the callback function, and assign directory in the callback accordingly?

(of course, I can create different callback functions and assign to each individual widgets, but I wanna adopt a slick approach.)

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Shamelessly copied from [Tkinter Callbacks](https://web.archive.org/web/20200302040546id_/http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-callbacks.htm).)
You could try something like:

```
def callback(number):
    print "button", number

Button(text="one",   command=lambda: callback(1))
Button(text="two",   command=lambda: callback(2))
Button(text="three", command=lambda: callback(3))
```

If you want the Button instance as a callback argument you can do something like:

```
import Tkinter
class ButtonBis(Tkinter.Button):
    def __init__(self, master=None, cnf={}, **kw):
        Tkinter.Button.__init__(self, master, cnf, command =self.callback, **kw)
    def callback(self):
        #Or whatever you want to do with self
        print "clicked!", self.cget('text')

b = ButtonBis(text="one")
b.pack()

b = ButtonBis(text="two")
b.pack()

b = ButtonBis(text="three")
b.pack()

Tkinter.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi dude, the 1st one is easy enough to implement, whereas the 2nd one for me is a bit baffling for the time being (involving OOP). I noticed that new classes are often defined for the GUI application, can you give me some tips as to how to master this OOP in GUI application? (e.g. what material to read, perhaps some github page to recommend, etc). Thanks a lot!